# Nuxt 2/3: Is there a way to store components in an array and display them one after the other

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

A common pattern is to have an array of objects (say json data) and use an index to prop that data to a single component.

The use-case I am working on is: to array a set of components and the show them like a carousel with a next and previous button which will set the index of the array

if it were some object,

```
<script setup>

const arr = ref([{n:1, l:"one"}, {n:2, l:"two"}])

const ind = ref(0)

function next() {
  ref.value++
}

</script>

<template>
  <div>
      <p>{{ arr[ind].l }}</p>
      <button v-on:click="change">Next</button>
  </div>
```

I would like to achieve the same where the array is a set of different components that appear.

The only option I can think of is to make a conditional v-show. Something like

```
<template>
   <div>
     <comp1 v-show="ind==0"/>
     <comp2 v-show="ind==1"/>
     <comp3 v-show="ind==2/>
   </div>
   <button ...>Next</button>
</template>
```

I am looking for something more elegant if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think you're looking for a vue Dynamic Components:

```
<component :is="currentTab"></component>
```

read this for more information: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components